# Infer types for type constructor

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types, rust-diesel

This might seem like a specific question but I'll try to generalize it as much as possible. Feel free to edit the title as I'm kind of Rust newbie and don't know how to phrase it concisely.

What I want to do is best explained by example.

I'm using diesel and generated `schema.rs` which defines the tables `Cats` and `Dogs` (with the `table!` macro).

Now I wrote `get_all` functions for `Cat` and `Dog` (2 Structs which I implemented)

```
pub fn get_all_cats(connection: &PgConnection) -> Vec<Cat> {
    Cats
        .load::<Cat>(connection)
        .expect("Error")
}

pub fn get_all_dogs(connection: &PgConnection) -> Vec<Dog> {
    Dogs
        .load::<Dog>(connection)
        .expect("Error")
}
```

But as they basically do the same I would love to generalize them in a `get_all<T>` method.

I thought of creating a trait:

```
trait GetAll<T=Self> {
   fn get_all(conn: &PgConnection) -> Vec<T> {
      Resource.load::<T>(conn)
   }
}
```

And of course I need to define `Resource` now, which is either `Cats` or `Dogs`. So I wanted to do a workaround and define a method `get_resource` which I can override in `Cat` and `Dog` to give their respected Resource. This is of type `diesel::query_dsl::RunQueryDsl<Conn>`.

The Problem is that I don't have a clue what type constraints `Conn` must implement (and then the Type Arguments of that Type, and so on) and I think there should be an easier way then reverse engineering the whole Type-Chain from diesel.

```
trait GetAll<T=Self> {
   fn get_resource() -> diesel::query_dsl::RunQueryDsl;

   fn get_all(conn: &PgConnection) -> Vec<T> {
      get_resource().load::<T>(conn)
   }
}
```

This fails with `expected 1 type argument`

Is there a "fix" for my approach (e.g. the compiler infers the type automatically) or is the design broken? If the latter is the case, how can I generalize the `get_all` method?

PS: The same goes for the `Queryable` trait, which should be a constraint for `T`, but again requires 2 Type Parameters.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions for `Cat`/`Cats` and `Dog`/`Dogs`?

Comment: They are pretty irrelevant, but `pub Struct Cat { pub id: Uuid }` and `pub Struct Dog { pub id: Uuid }` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need an associated type on your trait. This lets you express the fact that data struct has a unique resource type associated with it.

```
trait GetAll {
    type Resource; 
    fn get_all(conn: &PgConnection) -> Vec<Self> {
        Self::Resource::load::<Self>(conn)
    }
}

impl GetAll for Dog {
    type Resource = Dogs;
}

impl GetAll for Cat {
    type Resource = Cats;
}
```

Which you should be able to use like this:

```
let dogs = Dog::get_all(&conn);
let cats = Cat::get_all(&conn);
```

Comment: Nice Idea, but Resource is not a type, it is an instance of `diesel::query_dsl::RunQueryDsl` if I understand it correctly.

Nevertheless I could do `type Resource;` and then use this type in the method signature for `get_resource() -> Resource`, right?

Comment: nvm. I would still need to tell the compiler that `Resource` has a method `.load()`, so I again need to constrain it, which is the problem that I have in the first place.

Comment: @KillPinguin I think you need to provide more information about all of the types involved.